# LinearLayouts: One fixed and one with variable height

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout

I would like to add a top bar with two buttons in a vertical LinearLayout with the height of exactly 100 dp.

So I would like a 100 dp high view, and a variable high view below it.

I am trying this code, but it doesn't work. I can see that it doesn't accept 100 dp as a valid value, but I don't know how to achieve what I would like to do with LinearLayout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100 dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button 1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button 2" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </View>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: remove space in 100 dp (`100dp`)

Comment: Then how will my top bar become exactly 100 dp high?

Comment: because you are giving it `100dp` height

Comment: try `100dp` instead of `100 dp`

Comment: Oh ... wow. Sorry, I get it now. LOL, it's late here. :D

Comment: no problem, better care next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try after remove space in `100dp`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button 1" />

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button 2" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </View>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You added space between 100 and dp (100 dp), remove space and compile you code.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button 1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button 2" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </View>
</LinearLayout>
```